# Удаление класса CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Недавно начал изучать CSS/HTML/JAVA решил на страницу добавить индикатор загрузки, нашел интересное решение https://codepen.io/meowwwls/pen/PBBzRL но как бы глупо это не звучало, удалить после загрузки страницы этот индикатор не получается, пробовал решения

```
var _loading_spinner = setInterval(function ()
{
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
        var $page_loading = document.getElementsByClassName('loader__wrap').remove(),
            $body = document.body || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
            speed = 300, delay = 300;
        if ((typeof $page_loading !== 'undefined') && ($page_loading != null))
        {
            setTimeout(function ()
            {
                var transition = 'opacity ' + speed.toString() + 'ms ease',
                    removeCssClass = function (obj, className)
                    {
                        obj.className = obj.className.replace(className, '').replace('  ', ' ');
                    };
                removeCssClass($body, 'loader__wrap');
                $page_loading.remove("loader__wrap");
                setTimeout(function ()
                {
                    $page_loading.parentNode.removeChild($page_loading);
                }, speed + 10);
            },
            delay);
        }
        clearInterval(_loading_spinner);
    }
}, 10);
```

**как удалить этот скрипт после загрузки**

Comment: `CSS/HTML/JAVA` - а зачем вы изучаете `JAVA`?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko наверное сервлеты ваяет, а CSS-ом терминалы да консоли стилизует)))

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, скорее всего автор считает что java и javascript - это одно и тоже.. Эх, печально..

Answer (score 1):

Немного изменил код Javascript

1. для $page_loading (5 строка) удалил `.remove`
2. строка 21 - первый елемент массива с класом `loader__wrap`

```js
var _loading_spinner = setInterval(function ()
{
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
        var $page_loading = document.getElementsByClassName('loader__wrap'),
            $body = document.body || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
            speed = 300, delay = 300;
        if ((typeof $page_loading !== 'undefined') && ($page_loading != null))
        {
            setTimeout(function ()
            {
                var transition = 'opacity ' + speed.toString() + 'ms ease',
                    removeCssClass = function (obj, className)
                    {
                        obj.className = obj.className.replace(className, '').replace('  ', ' ');
                    };
                removeCssClass($body, 'loader__wrap');
                $page_loading[0].remove();
                setTimeout(function ()
                {
                    $page_loading[0].parentNode.removeChild($page_loading);
                }, speed + 10);
            },
            delay);
        } else{
     console.log($page_loading);
    }
        clearInterval(_loading_spinner);
    }
}, 10);
```